# Why is this not Community Wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I just noticed that my question, [Windows Setup could not configure Windows to run on this computer's hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/171200/windows-setup-could-not-configure-windows-to-run-on-this-computers-hardware) is still not Community Wiki after [<s>11</s> 13 revisions](https://superuser.com/posts/171200/revisions). It's odd because according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741) on [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), posts are automatically converted to Community Wiki after 10 revisions.

Comment: BTW, I'd prefer if it wasn't CW, just wondering why it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently after 18 revisions by 3 different users, it finally got converted to Community Wiki.

Comment: Um, congrats ? :-p

Answer (score 1):

Strange, my 12th revision didn't trigger switch to CW. Note [that answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741) mentions:

> the rules outlined above are based on observations; the actual behavior of SO is subject to change without notice, and may well have done so since this was last updated.

It might be plausible that the limit has been increased ?

---

Went digging further, and [this answer](https://superuser.com/posts/181722/revisions) got converted to CW on the 11th edit. Are the limits different for questions and answers ?

Comment: Perhaps its the frequency of the edits?

Comment: They are probably different...

Comment: @Mark - Perhaps. @Hello's post was edited over a period of several days,  but the one I linked had all revisions on a single day